# Reusing OLEDB parameters

Tags: c#, ado.net, oledb

How do we create a named parameter in OLEDB? I have a complex query and using ? as parameter does not serve my purpose since I will be reusing the parameter in the union statement of the query. How can we address the issue of reusing the same parameter multiple times in the same query. I am using .net v2.0 framework vb.net, and connecting to SQL server via sqloledb provider and OLEDB driver. Sample code attached

```
  Public Function ExecuteGetDatasetChild(ByVal commandstring As String) As System.Data.DataSet Implements IDBHelper.ExecuteGetDataset
        Dim theAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(commandstring, theConnection)
        Dim theData As System.Data.DataSet = New DataSet
        theData.ExtendedProperties.Add("commandstring", commandstring)
        theAdapter.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = commandTimeout
        'theAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
        theAdapter.Fill(theData, "defaultTable")
        Return (theData)
    End Function
```

Comment: What database are you using.  OLEDB is only a driver to connect to a database and does not specify the structure of the queries which depends on the database being used.

Comment: You should use the specific driver for the DBMS you are using. For example SqlClient for SQL Server. Then you should be able to use named parameters

Comment: I am using a SQL Database with sqloledb provider